# Does present perfect imply several times in this example?

Tags: present-perfect

If I say: I've seen him at the supermarket" does this imply I've seen him several times at the supermarket or can I say it if I've seen him only once (without including the word "once")?

In other words does the present perfect always imply several times? Some natives seem to think so.

To me "I've seen him at the supermarket" means I've had the experience of seeing him at the supermarket and it says nothing about how many times I've seen him. So even if it was only once I can use present perfect. Correct?

Comment: 'I've seen him…' implies seeing him several times when, and only when it's said in contrast to 'I saw him…'

You can I say that if you've seen him only once, though the context might change that.

Either way, the present perfect implies several times only in specific contexts; never in or of itself.

Comment: I don't understand "in contrast to I saw him". You can say "I've seen him once/several times, but you can also say "I saw him once/several times.

Comment: What is the trouble with 'in contrast to "I saw him" '?

By itself, 'I've seen him…' might imply that anything was seen 'several times' - or it might not.

In contrast/ by comparison/ as against/ on the other hand/ in the context of 'I saw him…' the meaning of 'I've seen him…' is no longer self-defined.

'I saw him…' by itself means one thing.

'I've seen him…' by itself means one thing.

'I saw him' in contrast to/ by comparison to/ as against/ on the other hand from/ in the context of 'I've seen him…' necessarily changes the value of either statement.

Answer (score 2):

'I've seen him at the supermarket' says nothing about how many times you've seen him; merely that you saw him at the supermarket at least
once.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

> I've seen him at the supermarket.

is most often used when the speaker has seen the person referred to on multiple occasions. In the absence of context, that is how most fluent speakers would interpret it, i think. I won't say it is **wrong** to use when the speaker has seen the other person only once, but it is likely to confuse or mislead a listener

Comment: If I say: "I've seen him at the supermarket today" does this imply several times as well?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also, I don't see anything wrong with "I know he's a great supporter of independent stores, but I _have_ seen him at the supermarket"(which could mean only once).

Comment: @anouk I agree with the comment by  
Kate Bunting. A qualifier such as "today" or "last week", or her suggested context removes any implication of multiple occasions.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Does "I've seen him at the supermarket today" sound odd as a sentence?

Comment: No - I would have said so in my earlier comment if that had been the case!

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin In your answer you say "I've seen him at the supermarket"says nothing about how many times you've seen him and then you say "it's wrong to use "I've seen" when you've seen the subject only once. That's really confusing. Like I said both "I've seen him once/several times" and "I saw him once/ several times" are both valid sentences.

Comment: @Anouk I'm sorry, there was some kind of mistake in my last to David, which I'm now deleting, which will leave your last Comment hanging on a very odd limb.

Comment: David, it might well be that 'I've seen him at the supermarket' is most often used when someone has been seen on multiple occasions and do you insist 'most often' is the only useful point? I suggest that in the absence of context, most fluent speakers will be quite flexible in their interpretation. In my view, what's most likely to confuse or mislead anyone is your interpretation, because that interpretation clearly relies on facts not in evidence.